# discord.js not playing audio file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to play an audio file but, for some reason it's not playing anything, it's firing `end` event instead of `start` event, right after the bot is connected to voice channel.

```
client.on('message', message => {
      if(message.content.startsWith('!play')) {

      if(!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('connect to voice channel first');

      message.member.voiceChannel.join()
        .then(connection => { 

            console.log("Joined voice channel!");

            const dispatcher = connection.playFile(require("path").join(__dirname, './myfile.mp3'));

            dispatcher.on('start', () => { //not working
                dispatcher.setVolume(0.70);
                console.log("Playing");
            }); 

            dispatcher.on('error', (err) => console.log(err)); //no errors

            dispatcher.on('end', end => { //working fine
                console.log("Finished");
                console.log("End: " + end);
                message.member.voiceChannel.leave()
            });
        });

}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed `ffmpeg-binaries` from `node-modules` and installed `ffmpeg` using `sudo apt` and it's working fine now. The problem was that, i had both of these libraries installed.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=playFile the path to the file has to be an **absolute path**.

[image: arguments]

#### To solve this issue:

You can use the module `path` (no need to download) and the global __dirname to get the absolute path.

```js
const dispatcher = connection.playFile(require("path").join(__dirname, './myfile.mp3'));
```

Comment: Still not working, btw i also tried using this [discord-bot](https://github.com/TannerGabriel/discord-bot) from github but this isn't working either.

Comment: Do you have ffmpeg and node-opus or opusscript installed?

Comment: I guess you can go to Discord.js official discord and ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to mention that for me neoney's answer worked, but it threw an error on connection.playFile, what finally ended up working for me was:

```
const dispatcher = connection.play(require("path").join(__dirname, './myfile.mp3'));
```

Note that you can also use (__dirname, '**../myFolderName**/myfile.mp3') in the parenthesis to go out of the current folder and play from within another named folder up one directory.

For more detail on the complete setup, there is a decent video/channel here by CodeLyon:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0lsD7U0JSI&t=917s